# How to use libVLC headers for Android on windows platform without building the whole library

Tags: android, libvlc

Is there a way to just add the headers of libVlc without going through the whole compilation process.

Comment: Have you tried anything or searched in google!!

Comment: Yes, but all that i get is going through the whole process of building the libvlc and unsuccessful attempts of doing so on windows environment.I dont need the raw library and therefore i am enquiring where to get the set of already built header that i can just attach with my project.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean in your comment about "already built header" and "raw library".

If you only want the source headers (e.g. to compile against), then you can get the source code from the official VideoLAN git repository at `http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=summary`.

The git source code has various forks/branches for the various released versions of vlc, and there are tags for each version.

So `git clone` the repository you need and find the tag for the version you're interested in.

Then, you will find the LibVLC headers in "vlc/include/vlc", which you can add to your project include path.

If you want something else, like pre-built LibVLC binaries for your platform then that is something else and has to be custom-built for the particular Android platform architecture that you are targeting. It is pretty easy to build VLC generally on Linux, you could do it in a Linux VirtualBox if you only have a Windows box, and then follow the instructions at `https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile`. Those instructions are too long to duplicate here.

Comment: I think he means that he just want to **use** the library, does not need to **build** the library! So there should be some library files that we can basicly import into our `android project` on `Windows` PC.

Comment: So clone the tag you want from git like the answer says.